# Transformer core shape for IF application?

Tags: transformer, if

I am looking for transformer to use with MC1350 IF amplifier.

Searching online, reference boards seems to use Canned type transformer as shown below.

[image]

The transformer has a center tap on the primary side, and looks similar(but not exactly like parts linked below.

[Datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/449/114211-202422.pdf)

However I could not find the parts with specification which I want, so I would like to DIY transformer.

The only core type I have E core that looks like below image

[image]

If I make transformer using different type of core, would performance be compromised?

Comment: Try coilcraft - they make kits of these parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If I make transformer using different type of core, would performance be compromised?*

Yes, that small shielded transformer on the PCB is used for (radio) signals. Note how it has a "screwhole", this is used to tuning the combination (transformer + other components on the PCB) to a certain frequency in order to filter out that frequency. The components for a resonant tank and are used as a Bandpass filter to suppress unwanted signals for example.

The yellow transformers are for **power applications** they're used in flyback power converters like power adapters. They're designed to turn electric energy into magnetic energy and back. Efficiency is key here.

The power transformers are not designed for resonating at a specific frequency, they're not tunable, they might be non-linear (harming your radio signal).

All in all, allthough they're both transformers of some sort they serve entirely different purposes and cannot be exchanged.